# Está pergunta está dentro ou fora do escopo do site?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

Está pergunta está dentro ou fora do escopo do site?

[Empresa pode vigiar tudo que funcionário faz no computador do trabalho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69337/empresa-pode-vigiar-tudo-que-funcion%C3%A1rio-faz-no-computador-do-trabalho)

Eu também fui um dos que votei para fechar, mas tive de ir ver de novo e tenho muitas dúvidas...

Comment: Bom dia @JorgeB eu mesmo fiquei na dúvida na hora de escreve-la, mas como era uma necessidade acabei postando ciente de que poderia ser suspensa, talvez a pergunta deveria ser feita aqui dentro do meta em vez  de lá ? Ou realmente não cabe esse tipo de pergunta no SO ?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA no Meta com certeza não, o Meta trata o funcionamento do site em si. Agora, se a pergunta cabe ou não no SOPT, é o que esse tópico visa discutir.

Comment: @Math, então perguntas relativas a analise de projeto, antes do desenvolvimento o SO não aceita ?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA eu não sei... Por isso pus aqui a pergunta para as pessoas dizerem o que acham...

Comment: @SneepSNinjA o site costuma mudar e se adaptar a novas regras e costumes, desde que seja da vontade da comunidade. Para que haja uma mudança é necessário primeiro haver a necessidade, e daí o pessoal discute, se acharem que o assunto cabe, bem, senão, tchau :) Uma das maiores discussões que tivemos sobre o que era on ou off topic pode ser visto aqui: [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/3117) Acho que boa parte do que foi discutido lá ainda está valendo.

Comment: @Math É realmente quando o assunto sai do foco "código fonte" alguns não aceitam, mas vi no seu link, dentro de outro http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23185/como-fazer-o-or%C3%A7amento-inicial-de-um-projeto-de-software Uma pergunta sobre orçamento de software foi muito bem aceita e ao meu ver fica muito próxima da minha pergunta no sentido de quem desenvolve sistemas precisa desse tipo de perguntas/respostas

Comment: Mesmo que suportasse o escopo, em minha opinião a única pessoa capacitada a responder seria um Advogado com conhecimento de causas trabalhistas, por mais que uma pessoa possa entender as bases "da lei", ainda sim seria necessário a interpretação de alguém que atua e se fosse uma situação que estive-se ocorrendo juridicamente, ainda sim o juiz poderia considerar outros pontos no processo. Em outras palavras, não é só off-topic por não se tratar de programação, é off-topic por ser algo que "não pode ser respondido" por *qualquer pessoa*, levando em consideração que a lei muda de país para país.

Comment: Ao meu ver está pergunta também é off-topic: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69324/3635 pois se trata de um pedido/sugestão de software/api, mesmo aparentando dentro do escopo.

Comment: Comunidade sobre o assunto: [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) (em Inglês, claro..)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ao meu ver essa pergunta sai do escopo do site por estar mais ligada a área jurídica do que TI em si. Não vejo ninguém diferente de algum advogado que possa dar uma resposta confiável sobre esse assunto.

Temos também outro problema: a legislação aqui é diferente que em Portugal. As leis válidas aqui não são as mesmas lá, o que torna a resposta válida somente no Brasil.

Minha opinião é que, caso não exista nenhum advogado na comunidade, qualquer resposta entra como "principalmente baseada em opiniões".

Por fim, como a lei está sujeita a interpretação, acredito que cada caso é um caso.

PS.: Que tal tentar [perguntar aqui (Law)<sup>en</sup>](https://law.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Excelente resposta @gmsantos, fizeste-me ver as coisas de outra forma.

Comment: @gmsantos Mesmo você supondo "principalmente baseada na sua opnião" que não há advogado na comunidade, as respostas são referenciadas em fontes confiáveis, mostrando que não é preciso ter registro na OAB para ter conhecimento das leis

Comment: Realmente, mas as repostas são referências em casos específicos. No Brasil a empresa pode monitorar seus ativos, mas se eu estiver em Portugal ou estiver trabalhando remotamente para uma empresa nas Bahamas, a empresa pode me monitorar? Ao meu ver uma resposta concreta a pergunta sai do escopo teórico de desenvolvimento de software e pertence a área jurídica.

Answer (score 5):

Achei a resposta do [@gustavox](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3965/3635) boa, mas (o mas do "mas") mesmo que a pergunta possa ter respostas *"boas"* e *"solidas"* ainda sim isto não tem relação alguma com **programação/desenvolvimento** e **configuração de softwares/ambientes para desenvolvimento**.

O autor usou como justificativa o [*problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), mas isto não faz sentido, pois eu poderia usar o mesmo argumento para fazer uma pergunta assim *"Meu monitor que eu uso no computador para programar não está funcionando"*, os pontos são:

1. Não é um *problema pratico bem definido* ligado ao **desenvolvimento do software**
2. É um "problema" ligado as leis/jurídico/contrato/empresas

Acredito que o local ideal para se fazer este tipo de pergunta seria perguntar na comunidade http://law.stackexchange.com (como sugerido pelo [@gmsantos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3949/3635))

Apesar da comunidade ser bem recente (17/06/2015)

- public beta iniciou há 8 dias atrás
- private beta iniciou há 21 dias atrás

Ainda sim considero o local mais apropriado.

Note que eles usam tags como `united-states`, `united-king`, `hong-kong` então se for abrir uma questão lá você poderá criar as tags `brazil` e/ou `portugal`.

Uma outra questão é que assim como frequentamos o http://superuser.com que usa o inglês, mas é aberto para o "mundo", devemos usar comunidades apropriadas para o assunto, assim concentrando perguntas boas em locais apropriados e não misturando assuntos diversificados.

E se um dia o StackExchange der maior suporte para comunidades em outros idiomas, podemos sugerir o `pt.law.stackexchange.com` e `pt.superuser.com` (se realmente for interessante)

Comment: Concordo com esse raciocínio.

Comment: Vish! :-) Cara, até me gelou a espinha pensar que era uma comunidade jurídica da SE em pt-br! (essa ideia é minha!!! :P) :-) (eu vi que tem as tags específicas dos países, mas daí não teria que criar a pergunta e a resposta em inglês?) Sobre a pergunta, como eu disse, se é o suficiente ou não a comunidade decide. Eu só quero que o SOpt continue sendo esta ferramenta maravilhosa de responder perguntas de programação para todos aqueles que sabem fazer uma pergunta (inclusive um novato como eu).

Comment: Pessoalmente acho que a resposta pode ajudar muitos programadores a ter uma boa ideia de onde estão pisando, mas como eu disse, se isso for atrapalhar de alguma forma (ou mesmo só criar discórdia) acho preferível que fique fora mesmo. Até porque, quando eu tiver a "minha" SE jurídica, não haverá perguntas de programação lá. ;)

Comment: eheuhehu sua edição tá roubando a minha ideia!!! :-)

Comment: Sobre criar a SE em pt-br! :)

Comment: @gustavox te juro que eu não tinha notado isto rs. Eu a apoio, desde que façamos uma campanha para os recém formados em direito (o tipo de pessoa que tem muitas duvidas) frequentarem a comunidade :)

Comment: Ah cara, isso seria incrível! Acho que cheguei a falar isso num comentário aqui mesmo no meta, mas acho que apaguei depois pq tinha ficado estranho/pretensioso (countdown pra apagar estes? haha). O mais difícil seria formar uma comunidade forte no início, pra ter um fluxo legal, e esta ideia dos formandos em Direito é muito boa. Quem sabe engajar uma grande universidade.., mas isso é bem sonho ainda, basta ver as comunidades com muito mais afinidade com programação que foram negadas né, tipo superuser...

Comment: @gustavox Acho que assim como começamos no StackOverflow original, podemos incentivar as pessoas frequentarem o `law.se`. Já seria bem interessante e traria bastante material para esta nova comunidade.

Comment: Pois é, já favoritei aqui o `law.se`. Meu inglês é bem precário, mas com a ajuda do google tradutor talvez eu me arrisque um pouco por lá. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sim, cada caso é um caso.

O AP deveria mesmo pagar um advogado **especialista**,  e fazer uma **consulta** para o caso específico dele, já que envolve uma decisão que poderia prejudicar a empresa, mas (sempre tem um mas neste tipo de resposta/comentário né haha) mas se for pra seguir este raciocínio, então as perguntas sobre `licenças` (e tudo o mais que não possuir uma resposta **exata**) também deveriam estar fora do escopo, e pelo mesmo motivo: apenas um advogado **especializado** poderia dar uma resposta que não fosse "baseada em opiniões", e mesmo assim com reservas.

Muito no Direito é "baseado em opiniões". Mesmo onde a lei é clara, e a jurisprudência é sólida, o entendimento pode variar nos primeiros graus de jurisdição (e você terá que enfrentar uma árdua batalha pra fazer valer o que os graus superiores entendem), ou pode simplesmente mudar (nos graus superiores) no curso do processo.

```
2 + 2 nem sempre é 4;
```

Não é como uma pergunta de programação, ou de matemática. Sempre depende de muita coisa.

Isto posto, ao meu ver a pergunta é válida, e tem respostas válidas e sólidas. Se isso é o suficiente, a comunidade é quem sabe.

Mas a resposta aceita, aliada ao entendimento do TST (a maior instância trabalhista do país, cujo entendimento só pode ser questionado, em casos muito específicos, no STF) que postei na minha resposta, proporciona com certeza um bom panorama da situação que o AP vai enfrentar pra manter seu programa na legalidade.

Com estes conhecimentos ele pode avaliar, inclusive, se o advogado que irá consultar possui realmente conhecimentos na área, e se está apto a opinar quanto ao melhor caminho a ser seguido.

Bom, é isso, só queria deixar um outro lado pra vocês pensarem.

Comment: Sua resposta e a do SneepS NinjA me fizerem decidir por votar em reabrir.

Comment: Concordo com o seu ponto de vista sobre pode conter respostas solidas, mas (o mas do "mas") é que a pergunta não se enquadra no desenvolvimento de softwares e nenhum ponto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tem razão sobre isso também

Comment: Comentei e dei +1 na resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento. Resumindo: Vcs é quem sabem! :-)

Comment: @Caffé Quero crer que no contexto esteja claro que não acho que só perguntas com respostas exatas devam estar no escopo. E se não está que fique: [eu não acho isso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2731/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-pedido-de-simples-opini%C3%A3o-e-de-recomenda%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-boas-pr%C3%A1ticas).  O que eu disse foi que "se for pra seguir esse raciocínio" (de que quando 'cada caso é um caso' é e impossível responder com certeza, então deveria estar fora do escopo), logo outras perguntas que caíssem na mesma situação também não deveriam estar no escopo...

Comment: Mas observando bem agora, acho que nem a pergunta e nem a resposta aceita falavam disso. :/ De qualquer forma, concordo com vc que exagerei ao estender para qualquer caso, mas o que você acha com relação às licenças? Se aplica o mesmo raciocínio do que neste caso (conhecimento específico fora da programação, mas que tem relevância para programadores por ser assunto relacionado)?

Comment: E tem um último argumento que esqueci de mencionar na resposta, mas fica registrado aqui: é que como o SOpt é feito uma imã para os aventureiros que querem criar um site ENQUANTO aprendem a programar, é muito possível que conhecimentos interdisciplinares estejam presentes aqui mais do que se imagina, e que certas questões relacionadas indiretamente à programação possam sim ter especialistas por aqui. E *data maxima venia* é este o caso; eu realmente sei do que estou falando. ;)

Comment: Eu já vi uma pergunta sobre licença onde o maior valor da resposta era mandar procurar um advogado - mas não sei se estamos falando da mesma pergunta. Para dizer o que eu acho teríamos que falar sobre uma pergunta em específico.

Comment: hahaha btw, acho possível dar boas respostas sobre licenças, mas não uma exata. Estou perguntando isso (e acho que por isso entrei em todo esse assunto hoje) porque já faz uns dias que estou trabalhando num wiki sobre licenças (Direito autoral, licenças e patentes - Coisas que o desenvolvedor web precisa saber), justamente porque tentei responder uma pergunta sobre isso e vi que uma resposta curta seria incompleta,  então resolvi criar o wiki pra servir como referência e responder apenas sucintamente, mas agora estou em dúvida se isso será bem vindo na comunidade...

Comment: A pergunta é [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69051/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-licen%C3%A7as-de-software-adotadas-atualmente-e-qual-seu-uso-mais-indic).

Comment: Com certeza absoluta conhecimentos interdisciplinares estão muito presentes aqui. Liderança por exemplo é uma competência importantíssima para um arquiteto de software, mas enquanto aqui é um bom lugar para o arquiteto fazer uma pergunta sobre "tiers" e "layers", não é um bom lugar para ele perguntar sobre como convencer o time a adotar sua solução. Quanto a esta pergunta sobre lincenças, eu entendo que ela não se enquadra aqui por vários motivos: ampla demais, não possui um foco ou um problema prático a ser resolvido - ela está mais a pedir um artigo ou uma tese sobre um assunto. (1 de 2)

Comment: Então o problema dela no SOpt não é ela não possuir uma resposta exata, porque inclusive ela provavelmente possui. Ela apenas não parece se enquadrar na nossa filosofia e nossa mecânica de perguntas e respostas (2 de 2).

Comment: Ok, entendi. Sobre a pergunta, acho que só esta parte pode ter uma resposta mais próxima do 'exato': "Como tais licenças devem ser aplicadas na atual versão?", já esta parte "quais seus benefícios (de forma resumida)?" é algo extramente dependente de um caso concreto... e esta outra parte "e quais outras estão em voga e sendo aplicada" é muito vaga e ampla. Mas para todas elas acho que eu poderia oferecer  uma boa resposta (sou especialista em direito do trabalho, mas tenho conhecimento para analisar a legislação incidente, e estou lendo várias teses e artigos pra desenvolver o wiki).

Comment: Bacana, provavelmente este wiki ficará bem legal e útil para a comunidade. Como você mesmo está demonstrando (descrevendo por que optou por não responder): o fato de uma pergunta ser do interesse de desenvolvedores ou o fato de ter alguém por aqui apto a respondê-la não a torna perfeita para ser perguntada aqui. Para manter o alto valor do SOpt, é importante que sua filosofia seja preservada nas perguntas e respostas ou pelo menos na imensa maioria das perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Legal, você tem mesmo razão quanto a necessidade de manter a integridade do site, por isso que disse na resposta que só queria deixar um outro lado pras pessoas pensarem... Eu mesmo tenho dúvidas com relação à necessidade de todas estas perguntas estarem aqui (tanto sobre esta, quanto sobre licenças). É que lendo estas perguntas (quando são "aceitas", ou demoram pra ser suspensas), vejo sempre uma oportunidade muito boa pra retribuir o que a comunidade tem feito por mim (e ganhar uns pontinhos no processo né :P). (P.S: Você argumenta muito bem, com certeza seria um bom advogado :-) )

Comment: @gustavox (off-topic) Li que estava procurando uma parada sobre licenças. Esse site aqui é bem legal : http://choosealicense.com/ :)

Comment: @gmsantos Esse site é legal mesmo, e tem em pt-br também http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/. O da creative commons é mais legal ainda https://creativecommons.org/choose/ (o sistema de escolha tbm em pt-br) mas é preciso entender uma série de conceitos importantes pra escolher corretamente uma licença, só ler estes sites não basta, e escolher somente à partir da resposta a algumas perguntas também não me parece o ideal. Ajuda muito, claro, principalmente como uma introdução, mas não acho prudente escolher a licença somente com bases nestas dicas.

Answer (score 1):

[A respeito de mais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

- Problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software

O problema é prático, a pergunta refere se é ou não legal fazer um determinado tipo de software, a resposta deve ser clara como a pergunta, sim ou não e referencia para a base da afirmação.

A duvida que se refere na distinção da lei em países e isso pode ser referenciado na pergunta/resposta para esclarecimento da mesma, isso não deixa a pergunta ampla, basta especificar que é no Brasil e teremos respostas tudo sim ou tudo não.

Por fim, ao meu ver uma pergunta que recebeu pontuação positiva é porque foi útil não só para o AP então estou satisfeito de ter ajudado não só a minha pessoa como parte da comunidade, mesmo que essa parte seja a minoria.

Comment: Sua resposta e a do gustavox me fizerem decidir por votar em reabrir.

Comment: @Math não me parece que "Empresa pode vigiar tudo que funcionário faz no computador do trabalho?" se enquadre naquele ponto. Não sei...

Comment: @JorgeB. não tinha pensado por esse lado, rs.. Foquei mais no resto da resposta. Acho que pode ficar aberta apesar de eu ainda estar um pouco em dúvida, o assunto realmente é discutível.

Comment: @Math a pergunta é boa e interessante, embora localizada BR. De qualquer forma é preciso ver 1º se está no escopo definido na central de ajuda; 2º se está ou estará no escopo definido por nós;

Comment: @Caffé a pergunta esta se referindo a um desenvolvimento de um software para monitoramento do Skype, só queria algumas respostas com algum amparo na lei, não me importa o que o juiz x ou y irá sentenciar, quero saber se é lícito tanto o software quando os contratos de política de empresa

Comment: Eu como desenvolvedor só me preocupo se serei processado pelo desenvolvimento, e preciso alertar a empresa se a política da empresa esta certa ou errada, ou ainda que se existe um risco a empresa fique ciente deste risco.

Comment: Meu argumento permanece: para estas perguntas, as repostas ainda serão de teor jurídico e não relacionadas ao desenvolvimento de software. O fato de você precisar de uma resposta ou mesmo de a sua pergunta ser do interesse dos profissinais da área (e monitoramento é do interesse de qualquer profissional que use um computador), não tornam o SOpt um bom lugar para perguntá-la. A presença da sua pergunta não é um crime, existem outras semelhantes por aí. Mas se não houver ao menos uma relutância em aceitar perguntas tão fora do escopo, no que isso daqui vai se transformar? ;-)

Comment: @Caffé agora entendi seu ponto de vista, é que as regras da comunidade não são restritas a código fonte, e isso me deixa em dúvidas na hora de postar esse tipo de pergunta, mas como achei que era de interesse comum a mais pessoas acabei postando, suspensa ou não é uma pergunta de interesse a comunidade ( ou parte dela)