# É legal fazer perguntas sobre legislação?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

**TL;DR** abriram uma pergunta de leis sobre software aqui no SOpt. Faz parte ou não do nosso escopo?

---

Eu encontrei uma pergunta sobre propriedade de código no SOpt:

[Direito sobre o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209007/direito-sobre-o-c%C3%B3digo/)

Acho que o assunto é pertinente, pois acredito que dez em cada dez usuários do SOpt sejam autores de código-fonte.

O problema é que enquanto escrevo há quatro votos para fechar a pergunta no link, por motivos de: fora de escopo.

Então eu verifiquei uns tópicos antigos aqui, e encontrei esse:

[Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Onde foi decidido por vinte e dois a um que legislações que afetem sistemas estão dentro do escopo.

Acho que quando fizemos aquelas votações não havia uma massa de perguntas para estudo como há hoje. Por isso acho que vale a pena <strike>problematizar</strike> reabrir a discussão, específica para esse tipo de assunto (legislação).

Comment: Relacionadas: [Dúvida sobre licenças para software livre é off-topic no SO em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2689/3117), [Está pergunta está dentro ou fora do escopo do site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3947/3117)

Comment: Creio que não faça parte do escopo. Mas não falando de regras e nem pela comunidade toda, em minha opinião eu acho muito bom sim falar disto e acho que temos espaço, claro que é o tipo de pergunta que *"anda em cima do muro"*, elas podem sim ser problemáticas ou úteis, creio que a solução seja analisar caso a caso e aproveitar pois o assunto pode ser muito útil, claro que **algumas** perguntas/respostas podem ser péssimas e só alguém com conhecimento jurídico deveria poder responde-las, neste caso acho que *flag/sinalizar* deveria também fazer parte ou até mesmo fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Reaberta a temporada de trocadilhos no meta :D

Comment: @bfavaretto boa xD

Comment: Sobre as questões legais, tenho dúvidas. Acho que a maioria dos usuários acharia bom poder ter mais informações sobre esses assuntos. O problema é achar quem possa responder com segurança. Senão vira coleção de achismos.

Comment: Eu não gosto muito embora algumas até dê pra responder. Quando é mais geral ainda vai, quando começa ficar mais específica, no fundo é consulta jurídica, quando a coisa fica séria, eu não acho que deveria aceitar. Eu já respondi as mais ingênuas. Note que ali nem é sobre legislação de software, mas que afetam o software, pode ser até sobre impostos :) Temos bacharel em direito aqui no site e ele acha que não é uma boa.

Answer (score 12):

Além dos problemas mencionados nas outras respostas, vale lembrar que nosso público em geral não é necessariamente qualificado para responder este tipo de assunto, com algumas exceções.

Mesmo que eventualmente surjam excelentes respostas (como já aconteceu), são casos pontuais, e que sequer podem ser votados adequadamente pelo resto do público que não tem o background na área (que imagino ser uma grande maioria). Existe muita probabilidade de uma resposta que contenha um equívoco imenso, mas que esteja bem formatada, receber uma votação positiva inadequada por falta de referência do leitor (já acontece quando o assunto é programação, imagine Direito).

Além disso o assunto já não fazia parte de nada listado no escopo do site. Tende a causar mais dano e gerar respostas tendenciosas do que resolver problemas reais. Não me entendam mal, é um assunto do **interesse** do programador sim, assim como a qualidade do seu teclado e monitor, assim como dúvidas sobre o mercado de trabalho em cada país, e outras mil coisas. O que por si só não traz nenhum dos exemplos para o nosso escopo.

Answer (score 8):

> Irei justificar o meu voto, mesmo sendo contra ele próprio

Eu sempre fui à favor desse tipo de pergunta no site. Todo programador iniciante tem dúvidas sobre algum tipo de legislação, seja para criação ou utilização de sistemas.

Mas, conforme foi me dito no início (não lembro por quem), nós temos alguns fatores, que são:

- Não temos somente PT-br aqui no site, ou seja, temos outras pessoas que falam português que não são Brasileiras;
- A maioria dos assuntos são judiciais, ou seja, as respostas sem entender as premissas poderiam ser errôneas;
- Poderiam ter respostas de acordo com o contrato do AR (autor da resposta), o que pode não ser a realidade do AP (Autor da pergunta).

Sobre [esta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) que você mencionou, poderia entrar no escopo, assim como outras, como [esta daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205631/20615).

Esse tipo de pergunta é uma dúvida para todo programador que está iniciando, e mais ainda para aqueles que não estão em uma empresa que conhece as normas.

Eu acharia muito bem vindo esse tipo de perguntas no site (claro, analisando cada caso separadamente), mas como a maioria foram fechadas e como geram discussões no [debate de pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57786/debate-da-pilha) eu optei por fechar. Não que exista algo com a pergunta e muito menos com a resposta (pelo contrário) e sim pela atitude que o site possui **hoje**.

Comment: Sem entrar no mérito se deve ter ou não, da sua resposta, vou focar na última frase: precisamos decidir se o que é válido ou não no site se o conteúdo realmente causa problema, se realmente é útil no sentido amplo, não apenas se tem uma informação, e se pode ser respondido pelos usuários típicos do site. Me desagrada o pensamento de muitos que algo deve ser aceito ou não de acordo com a atitude da comunidade. Não que eu seja contra isso, na verdade acho um excelente critério, só não pode ser o único. Principalmente para não aceitar precisa vir acompanhado de outros motivos.

Comment: @bigown Eu particularmente não votei somente por ser *aceito* ou não pela comunidade. Claro, isso teve um peso sim, mas eu coloquei três pontos na resposta que poderiam causar problemas **judiciais**, dependendo das respostas.

Comment: O comentário é mais geral mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Dando meu rápido pitaco: em última análise, é mais interessante para esse programador leigo que venha a fazer perguntas que, eh, bem... ele contrate um advogado!

Não é comum, e muito menos esperado, que computeiros tenham noção ampla de legislação, jurisprudência e os caramba a quatro, a ponto de saber que leis aplicam-se ou mesmo de saber se tais e tais contratos de concessão de código-fonte são legais ou não. Ainda que haja ou ou outro que saiba, ou mesmo um raro evento de um cara que seja ao mesmo tempo programador e advogado (e advogado especialista nesses casos), ele nem sempre poderá dar a resposta adequada. No fim, tudo depende do caso concreto.

Ainda que seja um assunto de interesse da comunidade, ela é de especialidade de um jurista.

Answer (score 5):

Não é uma resposta, relatório técnico e tampouco uma consultoria, é só um questionamento retórico e despretensioso, realizado por um leigo, sobre um dispositivo regulamentário da Ordem dos Advogados Brasileira.

> **Art. 4º**
> A prática de atos privativos de advocacia, por profissionais e
> sociedades não inscritos na OAB, **constitui exercício ilegal da
> profissão**.
> *Parágrafo único*. É defeso ao advogado prestar serviços de
> assessoria e consultoria jurídicas para terceiros, em sociedades que
> não possam ser registradas na OAB.
> **<sub>Fonte: [Regulamento Geral da OAB](https://www.oab.org.br/content/pdf/legislacaooab/regulamentogeral.pdf)</sub>**

No blog do JusBrasil encontra-se essa definição para a consultoria jurídica:

> Consultoria Jurídica é a análise legal da viabilidade de um Direito a
> partir do relato de um caso concreto, com a finalidade de adequar a
> norma, por meio de parecer jurídico, oral ou textual, em relação ao
> fato narrado, prestado por profissional com expertise do tema
> interrogado.
>
> Em leigas palavras é a apreciação da possibilidade de um Direito face
> à situação real e a lei, por profissional competente, concretizado
> presencialmente em uma reunião ou por relatório técnico, com fins
> elucidativos, que pode abranger todos os setores de atividade legal.
> <sub>Fonte: [Pollarini Marques de Souza,Daniel - JusBrasil Você sabe o que é consultoria jurídica?](https://danielpollarini.jusbrasil.com.br/artigos/873804617/voce-sabe-o-que-e-consultoria-juridica)</sub>

Ou seja no Brasil parece ser uma contravenção apresentar um parecer técnico como especialista sem ser advogado.
Aqui nos sites da rede StackExchange ao respondermos perguntas estamos sendo equiparados a especialistas pois [um dos objetivos da Empresa](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/13/changes-to-stack-exchange/):

> Fazer da internet um lugar melhor e trazer respostas de especialistas para as suas perguntas.

Ou seja, aparentemente, ao mantermos questões do âmbito legal brasileiro estaremos expondo nossos usuários, cujo não sejam constituídos advogados, a possíveis sanções legais caso inadvertidamente respondam questões sobre legislação pois e, talvez assim, estariam se equiparando a um especialista jurídico caracterizando uma consultoria. Eu não posso dizer nem que sim e que não, um advogado talvez possa dizer com precisão, e por conta dessa incerteza acho melhor não tratarmos de assuntos legais no site principal.

Comment: "*Eu não posso dizer nem que sim e que não, um advogado talvez possa dizer com precisão*" - essa com certeza seria a frase mais usada em respostas (caso fossem liberadas perguntas sobre legislação). É como disse [outra resposta](/a/6057/112052), a esmagadora maioria dos usuários do site não tem formação em direito e liberar perguntas do tipo faria mais mal do que bem.

Comment: @hkotsubo, isso se o AR responder sinceramente que leu a lei ou regulamentação e informar que não conseguiu decodificar o texto na integra.  Sendo um pouco mais pessimista e apostando contra o ego de muitos ARs, quantas respostas fomos obrigados a dar no site principal porque os ARs leram a pergunta, leram a documentação e escreveram coisas absurdas ou opostas ao que foi perguntado ou que ao que estava documentado. Como disse a resposta que citou, nessa area erros tendem a causar danos.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme comentou o @GuilhermeNascimento,

> ...é o tipo de pergunta que "**anda em cima do muro**", elas podem sim ser
>   problemáticas ou úte...

É realmente complicado discernir quando pode ser aceito ou não.

Há casos simples onde acredito permitir como também há casos complexos onde uma resposta se tornaria ampla demais.

Além do mais, como colocado pelo @Randrade, muitos dos membros não vivem no Brasil. Eu sou um desses.

No geral, legislações são muito semelhantes no mundo inteiro mas sempre possuem alguma peculiaridade. Portanto, nem sempre uma resposta abrangerá globalmente, tornando-se em algo muito localizado, específico daquela região.

Resumindo, acredito que podemos permitir desde que o tema seja útil globalmente e não seja amplo demais.