# Não são on-topic mesmo?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Aproveitando a [pergunta do Renan](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6041/101) que botou o assunto na roda, acho que podemos repensar alguns [assuntos sobre não ser *on-topic*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/101). Sintam-se livre para sugerir outras. Acho que algumas estão muito claras que ninguém quer, nem vou perder tempo.

> Administração e configuração do servidor de banco de dados, incluindo backup e afinação (tunning). Assunto não relacionados diretamente com o desenvolvimento em si.

Na prática está sendo aceito. Estaria "positivo" se eu pudesse votar agora. Vamos oficializar?

> - Orçamento de projetos de software
> - Questões relativas à contratação de terceiros para projetos de desenvolvimento (seja do ponto de vista do contratante [terceirização] ou do contratado [mais comum])

Me parece algo quase igual ao que está bem negativado e nunca foi aceito, por mim continua assim.

> Dúvidas ou erros na utilização ou configuração de Softwares
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> Mensagens de erro no processo de instalação de um software
> Mensagens de erro ao iniciar um software ( instalou mas não inicia o programa )
> Mensagens de erro durante o funcionamento do software
> ```
>
> Exemplo de programas que pode aconter isso:
>
> ```
> Mysql
> Apache
> Tomcat
> Eclipse
> NetBeans
> Samba
> ```
>
> Softwares estes que sejam comum entre pessoas da area de TI e/ou utilizados pelos mesmos

Já estão sendo aceito, embora vez ou outra se fecha? Vamos padronizar as ações? Vamos manter?

> SEO, White Hat e Black Hat (Otimização que segue ou não diretrizes para melhorar o posicionamento em motores de busca)

Alguma coisa é aceita. Não acho que seja desenvolvimento de fato. Me parece coisa de marketing. Se estabelecer um limite que não entre em marketing talvez possa ser aceito.

> Assuntos relacionados a hospedagem, deploy, escalabilidade e computação em nuvem

Quase tudo está sendo aceito, até algumas coisas muito ruins, muito específicas. Não gosto da ideia, mas vai?

> ```
> Dúvidas sobre como utilizar o Excel ou similar: LibreOffice Calc e OpenOffice Calc.
>
> Inclui: dificuldades ao usar/criar fórmulas, tabela dinâmica, macros, filtros. (transformação de dados é programação, mesmo se feita
> ```
>
> visualmente)
>
> ```
> Exclui: dúvida de como instalar tais ferramentas, alterar cor, formatação simples.
> ```

Tem sido aceito sempre, acho que só falta oficializar.

> Técnicas de Hacking, Pentest e técnicas de invasão.

Fora as esdrúxulas acho que pode aceitar, o problema é que eu acho que nunca apareceu uma :)

> Localização para o português - ferramentas e técnicas de tradução de softwares, frameworks, templates e similares.

Tem que ter uma linha, mas pode ser útil, o que acham? Lembre-se que este tipo de coisa será muito raro. Não sei se teve algum caso que gerasse dúvida.

> - Arquitetura de engine de jogos existentes.
> - API de games específicos existentes (uso da API).
> - Projeto/implementação de engines para jogos.

Não consigo imaginar porque não aceitar. Tem muito voto favorável. Tranquilo, né?

> Gerência de Projeto específico para desenvolvimento de software (Agile, Scrum, RUP, etc.)

Tá com bastante voto, tem sido aceito, só oficializar também, certo?

> Code Golf: desafios de escrever determinado algoritmo na maneira mais curta possível ou com algum tipo de restrição.

Há aceitação na votação. Apareceu uns 2 ou 3, acho que todos fechados porque no fundo eram ruins, tinham outros problemas. Não está causando problema. Podemos pelo menos experimentar deixar por um tempo?

Note que estamos falando só sobre estar no tópico, não de qualidade e outros problemas que uma postagem assim pode ter, o que resultaria em fechamento por outros motivos.

Comment: Dando muita ênfase na última frase, acredito concordar contigo em todos os pontos, principalmente no último, em relação ao Code Golf, pois acho que a comunidade tem muito mais a ganhar do que perder nesse ponto.

Comment: `Fora as esdrúxulas acho que pode aceitar, o problema é que eu acho que nunca apareceu uma :)` passando aqui só pra lembrar da [mangueira de borracha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130149/expliquem-de-uma-forma-mais-simples-o-que-são-esses-ataques/)

Comment: @Renan é verdade :)

Comment: E quanto a perguntas sobre técnicas para proteger o software de ser crackeado e pirateado, isso seria on-topic?

Comment: Pode até ter on-topic, mas iria acontecer o mesmo que aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551016/how-to-make-a-good-anti-crack-protection - Podemos ver claramente uma auto promoção, e respostas baseados em  "eu acho". Ou igual aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550556/ive-found-my-software-as-cracked-download-on-internet-what-to-do - Posso estar errado mas não vejo possibilidade de respostas interessantes sobre anti pirataria devido já ter pesquisado muito no site em inglês e não ter encontrado nada legal a respeito.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri é uma observação válida.

Answer (score 6):

Eu gostava de deixar uma resposta com os tópicos que consideraria aceitáveis, há uma panóplia deles na sua lista que eu não considero razoável para esta comunidade.

Antes de proceder, gostaria de deixar aqui escrito que esta é uma comunidade de programadores para esclarecer perguntas sobre programação (erros de execução e compilação, esclarecimentos de funcionalidade, perguntas sobre algoritmos, complexidade e performance, linguagens, conceitos, termos e definições, técnicas de programação, padrões de desenho, linguagens, funcionamento do sistema operativo e as suas implicações no programa (threads, processos), base de dados, computação na nuvem, inteligência artificial, segurança informática, utilização de APIs). São estes e talvez mais uns poucos que me estejam a escapar, informática é um mundo grande.

Mas o ponto que quero chegar é por exemplo a seguinte sugestão

> Orçamento de projetos de software

Não me parece ser razoável. Tal como dei a entender esta comunidade é de programadores para responder a perguntas de programação e não de economia/gestão.

Imagine alguém aparecer aqui a perguntar como fazer um orçamento para construir uma casa. Voce vai dizer que essa pergunta é off-topic por não se tratar dum orçamento de um software? Se a sua resposta for sim então esse tópico não serve para nada.

---

Com isto em mente vamos então analizar se os tópicos são aceitáveis

> Administração e configuração do servidor de banco de dados, incluindo
>   backup e afinação (tunning). Assunto não relacionados diretamente com
>   o desenvolvimento em si.

**Perfeito!** Totalmente dentro do escopo do site. Questões sobre otimizações e performance sao bem vindas e devem ser colocadas.

> Orçamento de projetos de software

**Não.** Esta não é uma comunidade de economia/gestão.

> Questões relativas à contratação de terceiros para projetos de desenvolvimento (seja do ponto de vista do contratante [terceirização] ou do contratado [mais comum])

**Não.** Esta não é uma comunidade para assuntos legais (contratação é um assunto legal).

> Dúvidas ou erros na utilização ou configuração de Softwares

Só se se tratar dum software de produtividade de uso geral no mundo de programação (IDES, compiladores, RDBMS e poucos mais?). Os exemplos dados parecem encaixar.

> SEO, White Hat e Black Hat (Otimização que segue ou não diretrizes para melhorar o posicionamento em motores de busca)

**SEO sim(*)**. White e black hat desconhecido

Nao sei o que é white e black hat. Mas SEO está dentro do escopo. Eu nao sei muito sobre SEO mas pelo pouco que sei há técnicas que podem ser usadas alterando o `HTML` duma página, ou seja é algo que pode evolver trabalho dum programador (embora possam existir ou não ferramentas para facilitar o trabalho para outro tipo de profissionais).

> Técnicas de Hacking, Pentest e técnicas de invasão.

**Sim.(*)** Formule a pergunta para ser sobre segurança informática.

Em principio deve ser possível colocar estas perguntas na perspetiva do defensor. É totalmente legitimo saber como um ataque é feito. Mas mais importante que isso é saber como se defender dele. Se virmos [as perguntas de segurança informática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seguran%c3%a7a), vimos que as perguntas são quase sempre feitas nesta perspetiva. E na minha opinião é quando elas tem maior valor.

> Localização para o português - ferramentas e técnicas de tradução de softwares, frameworks, templates e similares.

**Sim**. Perguntas sobre APIs, seja qual for o fim, são bem-vindas.

> Arquitetura de engine de jogos existentes.

**Não.**

A arquitetura de programas (quer sejam eles de jogos ou nao) é muitas vezes  proprietária. Além disso não deve ser trabalho da comunidade fazer análise de programas externos.

O conhecimento para este tipo de perguntas é muitas vezes saciado consultando os sites oficiais de determinado programa.

> API de games específicos existentes (uso da API).

**Sim.**

Se aceitamos perguntas sobre a API do Google e do Facebook, também aceitamos qualquer outra. Lá por ser um jogo não quer dizer nada.

> Projeto/implementação de engines para jogos.

**Não.(*)**

Nós não sabemos como arquitetar o seu projeto (quer seja ele ou não um jogo). É trabalho do perguntador desenhar e implementar o seu projeto. Contudo **se tiver uma dúvida sobre uma parte especifica da sua implementação pode coloca-la**.

> Gerência de Projeto específico para desenvolvimento de software (Agile, Scrum, RUP, etc.)

É (excecionalmente) aceite pela comunidade.

Tenham em mente que isto não são perguntas sobre programação, contudo o SOPT é uma das poucas comunidades portuguesas no SE e, ao contrário das comunidades inglesas, não pode ser transferido para outra comunidade.

É também aceite pelo motivo destas práticas serem relativamente comuns no mundo da programação.

> Code Golf: desafios de escrever determinado algoritmo na maneira mais curta possível ou com algum tipo de restrição.

**Não.**

Por favor utilizem a comunidade do [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) para este fim. Essa comunidade é muito mais ativa no tópico e terão mais gosto em participar nela.

O fato dessa comunidade ser uma comunidade inglesa não é uma desculpa para aceitarmos o tópico.

O code golf é uma prática para entretenimento e não para produtividade, nós queremos proporcionar-lhe conhecimento e encontrar os seus problemas. Se quer brincar com código faça no sitio adequado.

Comment: ótima resposta, o que não quer dizer que concordo com tudo, o que nem seria o objetivo aqui. Algumas que estavam lá no OP eu não coloquei porque pra mim não tem a menor chance de ser aceito um dia aqui :) O que posso estar enganado :P

Comment: `A comunidade não deve aceitar perguntas sobre atacar. Mas obviamente deve aceitar perguntas de como defender`, hum... vc refletiu bem sobre isso? Até onde eu sei os melhores "defensores" são aqueles que conhecem muito bem as técnicas de ataque e justamente por isso sabem se defender. Vc vai ver mais sobre isso quando estudar White/Gray/Black Hat. Acho que não há como um defensor não ter os conhecimentos de um atacante, pois ele precisa conhecer as brechas e como explorá-las para poder fechá-las adequadamente, para criar *honeypots* atrativos, etc.

Comment: @Douglas Tem razao. Vou colocar o mesmo texto por outras palavras. O que eu quiz dizer. É que normalmente é possível colocar a pergunta na perspetiva do defensor. É totalmente legitimo saber como um ataque éfeite mas mais importante que isso é saber como se defender dele.Se vir as perguntas elas sao quase sempre na perspetiva do defensor. Essas tem um valor acrescido óbivo.